# How to keep Koding VM alive?

Tags: remote-access, vps, koding

I set up a [Koding](https://koding.com/) account and I am able to access it via putty. 
However it seems that the VM will automatically turned off somehow. It even turns off while I am working on a file through putty. This problem is not mentioned in any doc or help neither. 
Is there a way to avoid that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That IS the deal. unless you buy an account, your account will be turned off after 15min of inactivity.